# Universal App XAML designer not showing

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

All I am doing is creating a new blank app: New Project - Windows - Universal - Blank App. Then open MainPage.xaml, and all I see is raw XAML, no Design tab. View Designer (shft-F7) does not help.

This is on Win 10, developer mode on.

It does not seem likely that something is wrong with the VS installation, because I when I open MSDN UWP samples, XAML files in those samples open just fine. I tried reinstalling VC++ 2015 redistributable, as suggested in one of the posts here, did not help.

XAML designer is enabled (Tools - Options - XAML Designer).

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be the fact that my project target version (right click on Project - Properties - Application) was Windows 10 Insider Preview (Build 10563). Changing it to Windows 10 (Build 10240) fixes the issue.